# Move N elements in array from back to front

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, slice, python-import

I have a text file contains 2 columns, I need to select one column of them as an array 
 which contains 200000 and cut N elements from this array and move them from back to front.

I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

files = glob.glob("input/*.txt")

for file in files:
     data_file = np.loadtxt(file)
     2nd_columns = data_file [:,1]
     2nd_columns_array = np.array(2nd_columns)

cut = 62859  # number of elements to cut
remain_points = 2nd_columns_array[:cut]
cut_points = 2nd_columns_array[cut:]
new_array = cut_points + remain_points
```

It doesn't work and gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (137141,) (62859,)
```

any help, please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to add values stored in both arrays and they have different shapes.

One of the ways is to use [numpy.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html?highlight=hstack#numpy.hstack):

```
new_array = np.hstack((2nd_columns_array[cut:], 2nd_columns_array[:cut]))
```

**Side notes:**

1. with your code you will reorder only 2nd column of the last file since reordering is outside of the `for` loop
2. you don't need to store `cut_poinsts` nor `remain_points` in separate variables. You can operate directly on the `2nd_columns_array`
3. you shouldn't name variables starting from a number

Comment: How can I operate my cut directly? I tried to do this but it doesn't work!

Comment: Exactly as I did it in the snippet above. You can directly use `2nd_columns_array` and both variables `remain_points` and `cut_points` are not needed in your code anymore.

Comment: @ machnic- It's working well. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for this process is [numpy.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

```
new_array = np.roll(2nd_column, cut)
```